# ActiveMQ Broker connectible only on Localhost

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic, loopback

Is there a way to run a loopback JMS adapter that will only be detected locally?

I'm not sure if my terminology is correct, but I want the ActiveMQ broker to only be connectible from the same machine that the broker is running on.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure it's connector is only listening on localhost

look in the config.xml files and change all 0.0.0.0 adresses to 127.0.0.1