# How is possible to allow connections to Apache ActiveMQ JMS broker only from localhost?

Tags: activemq-classic, broker

I need to allow connections to Apache ActiveMQ JMS broker only from localhost.

Can not find appropriate option here:
http://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri.html

How it is possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3669799/4516887

Comment: Thanks! I do not have `config.xml` but I need to change `ssl://0.0.0.0:61616` to `ssl://127.0.0.1:61616`

Comment: XML is the recommended way (http://activemq.apache.org/xml-configuration.html). Alternative to that is the config-uri (http://activemq.apache.org/broker-configuration-uri.html) - which is a different link to the one you provided in your question.